# Reg Exp for Date in format MM/YY

Tags: javascript, regex, date

I have mask for my date in MM/YY format. There must be **month >= then current**, and **year >= then current** year.

I have regexp pattern here:

`<input id="expiration" type="tel" placeholder="MM/YY" class="masked" pattern="(1[0-2]|0[1-9])\/(1[8-9]|2\d)" data-valid-example="12/18" onchange="onChangeInput(event)"/>`

Seems like it's ok for this format, but I still can write a year less than 18.

Need a little help from you, stack overflow.

Comment: `Seems like he's ok` Don't think so, parentheses are imbalanced

Comment: Please add the whole relevant code to the question.

Comment: Please **add the code to the question** by editing the question, not by dumping it in a comment.

Comment: in your comment, the input type is `tel`. According to the HTML5 specification, `<input type="tel">` is used for input fields that should contain a telephone number.
The `<input type="month">` allows the user to select a month and year.
Depending on browser support, a date picker can show up in the input field. I think this is more appropriate than trying to mask a telephone number...

Comment: Man, I have different task. I've asked only about Reg Exp. This pattern is ok or not for the this kind of date. Like current or more then current month and year

Answer (score 0):

The pattern seems fine, however as noted using an input type tel is likely not a good idea as it's semantically inconsistent.

You might try using script instead of relying on browser validation as support is patchy. Something like the following may suit.

```js
function validateInput(evt) {
  var re = new RegExp(this.pattern);
  var s = this.value;
  // Show whether value is valid or not when input is full
  document.querySelector('#s0').textContent = s.length < 5 || re.test(s)? '' : 'Invalid';
}

window.onload = function(){
  document.querySelector('#i0').addEventListener('input',validateInput, false);
};
```

```html
<input id="i0" type="text" placeholder="MM/YY" pattern="(1[0-2]|0[1-9])\/(1[8-9]|2\d)" maxlength="5"><br>
<span id="s0"></span>
```